# PHP elseif statement

Tags: php

I am using PHP browser detect and want to use an else if statement to redirect them to a different page dependant on the browser or include a certain file.. For now I am sampling redirect.

I am getting a syntax error and I am baffled why, here is the code:

```
if($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] == "firefox" . "13.0.1"){
    header("Location: newff.php");
  elseif($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] != "firefox" . "13.0.1"){
    header("Location: oldff.php");
  } elseif($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] == "msie" . "13.0.1") {
    header("Location: newie.php");
  } elseif($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] != "msie" . "13.0.1") {
    header("Location: oldie.php");
  } elseif($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] == "chrome" . "20.0.1132.47"){
    header("Location: newchrome.php");
  } elseif($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] != "chrome" . "20.0.1132.47"){
    header("Location: oldchrome.php");
  } elseif($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] == "safari" . "534.57.2"){
    header("Location: newsafari.php");
  } elseif($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] != "safari" . "534.57.2") {
    header("Location: oldsafari.php");
  } else {
    header("Location: other.php");
  }
```

Thanks

Ben

Comment: You're missing a `}` after the first `header` command.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but you're going to have to update this *every* time a browser updates it's version number... And there are *very* few reasons to have a different page for each browser.

Comment: Oh, and you should have `die();` after every `header(...);` call. (The `header(...);` function simply sends a string to the browser and doesn't end execution of the script, so anything after the conditional statement could be executed.)

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to use closing bracked after first if:

```
if($browser['name'] . $browser['version'] == "firefox" . "13.0.1") {
    header("Location: newff.php");
} // this is missing
```